# SQL : Check whether there is improvement of at least 1 level in the grade between multiple days

Tags: sql-server, lookup

I have a training institute data in which I will be having student number, Study, assessment grade and days. The concept is every day (Day 1 to day 7) for a single study there will be training happening and at end of training we will have assessment for that study. After Day 7, there will be a new study started and the same process is carried. Based on the assessment a Grade will be assigned.

The Grade data will be 1,2,3,4

What I need is, I need to check whether is there any improvement for the student in the study from Day 1 to day 7.

If there is at-least one level of improvement say, I need to classify it as Improved. Below is few scenarios for example

Scenario 1:

Grade for student 1 in the study 1 assessment

> Day 1:     3
>
> Day 2:     3
>   Day 3:     2
>   Day 4:     2
>   Day 5:     2
>   Day 6:     2
>
> Day 7:     2

If you check the above data the student has one level of improvement in day 2 when compared to day 1

Scenario 2:

Grade for student 2 in the study 1 assessment

> Day 1:     3
>
> Day 2:     3
>
> Day 3:     3
>
> Day 4:     1
>
> Day 5:     1
>
> Day 6:     2
>
> Day 7:     2

Likewise in the above data the student has two level of improvement in day 4 when compared to day 3

So I need to find out the improvement levels for the Day 1 to Day 7 and if there is improvement, i will mark the student as improved.

If there is no improvement from Day 1 to day 7 it has to be classified as Not Improved.

I have posted my table script for refrence as I am unable to create the table in sql fiddle.

```html
CREATE TABLE [DataBook1](
 [FolderName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [Grade] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [InstituteCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [StudentNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [StudyNo] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 6', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 2')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 1', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 3')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 2', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 3')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 3', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 3')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 4', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 3')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 5', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 3')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 6', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 3')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 4', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 4')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 5', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 4')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 6', N'1', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 4')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 1', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 1')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 2', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 1')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 3', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 1')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 4', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 1')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 5', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 1')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 6', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 1')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 2', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 2')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 3', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 2')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 4', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 2')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 5', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 2')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 7', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 2')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 7', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 3')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 1', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 4')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 2', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 4')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 3', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 4')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 7', N'2', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 4')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 7', N'3', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 1')
GO
INSERT [DataBook1] ([FolderName], [Grade], [InstituteCode], [StudentNumber], [StudyNo]) VALUES (N'Day 1', N'3', N'80-02', N'80-02-001', N'Study 2')
GO
```

I tried to use the row_number over function to get the values of previous rows however I was not able to get my desired output.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What if a student goes from 1-4-2 ?  Does that represent improvement or not.  The definition of improvement is no clear.

Comment: It will be considered as improvement. I want to see whether there is improvement at atleast one time. If there is a improvement and then it dips no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if there is *any* decrease in grade, you can use `lag()`:

```
select StudentNumber,
       (case when sum(case when grade < prev_grade then 1 else 0 end)
             then 'Improvement'
             else 'No Improvement'
        end) as flag
from (select db.*,
             lag(grade) over (partition by StudentNumber order by FolderName) as prev_grade
      from DataBook1 db
     ) db
group by StudentNumber;
```

However, I don't think this is a good measure of improvement, because you could have situations such as 2-2-2-2-2-3-2, and that doesn't seem like much improvement to me.

Comment: Hi, Yes. It wont be however I need an improvement at any one day. So your code fits for me. I just changed the case statement to case when db.Grade = db.prev_grade 
             then '0'
    WHEN db.prev_grade IS NULL THEN '0'
             else '1'
        end and i am able to get what I need. Thanks for your help.